# Define default action when $http returns certains status

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Is it possible to set a default action for `$http` in my app?

The idea would be that if any `$http` call in a controller, or service of my app would return 405, I could change to state 'login'

Something like this (of course this will not work at all, but I guess that shows the idea)

```
angular.module('app',[]).config(function($http){
    $http.error(function(error,state){
    if (state===405){
        do stuff
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interceptors to achieve this.

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
// optional method
'request': function(config) {
  // do something on success
  return config;
},

// optional method
'requestError': function(rejection) {
  // do something on error
  if (canRecover(rejection)) {
    return responseOrNewPromise
  }
  return $q.reject(rejection);
},



// optional method
'response': function(response) {
  // do something on success
  return response;
},

// optional method
'responseError': function(rejection) {
  // do something on error
  if (canRecover(rejection)) {
    return responseOrNewPromise
  }
  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
};
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');


// alternatively, register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
return {
'request': function(config) {
   // same as above
},

'response': function(response) {
   // same as above
}
};
});
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I've been looking for.
It's even damn smooth with the anonymous factory.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  //Do whatever you want on success
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  if(response.status == 405) {
    //Go to login
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution as for each API request made, you need to write the error part having the check for response code.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Even if we define a global errorCallback and pass it to $http, we should pass this global function every time. I didn't knew about interceptors, but I will hava a look to them. It sounds great. I like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help you:

```
       $http.get("url")
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.content = data;
           if (data == '405') {
          $state.go('login', {id: the_necesarry_id});                

           }
           else   {window.alert(' ');}
       })
       .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use [angularjs Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

```
 // interceptors.js

    .factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $injector) {
        return {
       'requestError': function(rejection) {
                // do something on error
                if(rejection.status === 405){
                   $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('login');                    
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
           },
      'responseError': function(rejection) {
                // do something on error
                if(rejection.status === 405){
                     $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('login');                     
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
             }
         };
    });


    // app.js

    app.config( function ($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

        ...
    });
```